# Trying to add a few audit fields to a table with inheritance -- issues with keys in the derived class

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm using Entity Framework Version 1.1.2.

I want to add two audit fields to EVERY table that I create in SQL Server: 
CreateUTC
LastChangeUTC

So I create a root abstract class with these two fields in it:

```
public abstract class Audit
{

    [Required, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime CreateUTC { get; set; }
    [Required, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime LastChangeUTC { get; set; }
}
```

And then I try to inherit the root Audit Class with the derived class below, which has a challenge of having a composite key.   Not all of my tables are like this; some simply have a primary key.

```
public class Province : Audit
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [MaxLength(25)]
    public string CountryId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [MaxLength(25)]
    public string ProvinceId { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string ProvinceDesc { get; set; }

}
```

But I run into this issue, every time I attempt to annotate any key in the derived class, stating that this isn't allowed:

A key cannot be configured on my derived class because it is a derived type.

A.)  How do I make it easy on myself to add the two fields to every table without explicitly, redundantly adding them to a class if I can't use inheritance?

B.) How do I keep the composite key on my derived class and order the inherited properties (my audit fields) to the bottom of the table, so that I end up with a table field/schema representation and order like this in SQL Server:

```
KEY CountryId

KEY ProvinceId     

ProvinceDesc 

CreateUTC

LastChangeUTC
```

Comment: You marked them as database generated...remove it if you want to manually assign a value.

Comment: Not worried about how I'm going to assign the UTC value to the date fields.  More worried about the error that I'm getting stating that my annotated composite key or any annotated key for that matter isn't allowed on the derived class.  In order to get to this table properly keyed, do I really have to add these audit fields explicitly to every class?

Comment: Do not include `Audit` class in your EF model. The properties will be added in each derived class but the base class must not be part of model.
For `Key` attribute, you cannot define composite key using attribute, you must use fluent API.
To control the ordering of properties edit migration file